Waterproofing wooden support-beam over small sewage pit
Outset
A hut in a garden colony with running water but no connection to the sewers has a small sewage pit (2.50 x 0.80 x 1.20 m LWD) at the back of the hut, right in front of two tool shacks. The existing cover made from OSB and wood planks about 5 years ago is almost rotten through, demanding replacement.
Idea
In order for the solution to last a bit longer than 5 years, we're thinking about purchasing glass fiber reinforced plastic boards to cover the pit. Since the boards need to take the weight of one or two persons walking on them and getting stuff out of/putting stuff into the tool shacks, a support beam (10x10 cm or even 15x15 cm) running the whole length of the pit seems to be necessary. Wood is our material of choice, since it can easily be purchased and shortened so it fits the protrusions near the top of the pit.
Question
How would we go about water/steam proofing the support beam so it lasts about a decade?

Use pressure treated?

Why is the cover rotten if it's inside the hut?

@jay613 "at the back of the hut" = "behind, at the back side"

Oh, so the pit is outdoors?  In between the hut and the shacks?   In that case, what is the relevance of those buildings?  You just want to cover an outdoor pit with an opening 2.5x0.8, is that right?

I want to cover it, and it should be safe to walk over, dismissing e.g. the option of a slanted "roof".

Where are you finding FRP panels suitable to carry human weight (even over a short span)? Most I've seen are floppy as banana peels.

This question also depends on what products you have available. The involvement of a sewage pit implies that you're in a remote area with limited resources. You may need to revise to ask something more specific.

Nope, no limited resources, only limited tools. As stated, this is a garden colony as commonly found in and around a lot of middle european cities.
